# Unique constraint in PL/SQL of date field limited to the year

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

In one table I have an unique constraint over a `VARCHAR2` and a `DATE` field. All works fine!

Now, I just want to consider only (!) the year of the `DATE` field in my unique constraint.

Are there any opportunities in `PL/SQL` to do such things?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for PL/SQL here, just create a unique index on the year:

```
create unique index unique_year 
  on the_table (the_varchar_column, extract(year from the_date_column));
```

Comment: Thanks, dude! Why do you use an unique index, not an unique constraint?

Comment: @mrbela You would need the unique constraint if you want a **foreign key** to reference this column. Also, a **unique constraint** does not necessarily creates an **index** or an **UNIQUE index**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: a unique constraint _will_ create a unique index (unless you tell it to use an existing non-unique index)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A unique constraint *could* use **existing non-unique index** and not necessarily create unique index. `CREATE TABLE t( A NUMBER, b NUMBER );
CREATE INDEX t_indx ON t(A,b);
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_unq UNIQUE(a);
SELECT index_type, uniqueness FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name = 'T';`

Comment: Can you help me why `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT MY_CONSTRAINT_NAME UNIQUE (MY_VARCHAR, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATETIME));` does not work? I am getting the SQL exception ORA-00904.